# Spring Boot Hibernate Postgres function - No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I've the following function in POSTGRES:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_number_of_trips_by_lines()
    RETURNS TABLE(total bigint, line_id varchar(50))
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
        BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY select count(*), cast(rio.line_id as varchar(50)) from stop_times stio
                         inner join trips tio on stio.trip_id = tio.trip_id
                         inner join routes rio on rio.route_id = tio.route_id
                         where stio.stop_sequence = 1
                         group by rio.line_id;
        END;
    $function$
    ;
```

And I'm trying to get the result from a rest controller, with the following method:

```
@GetMapping("trips-by-line")
List GetSpNumberOfTripsByLine() throws Exception {
    try {
        List list = entityManager
                .createNativeQuery("SELECT public.sp_number_of_trips_by_lines();").getResultList();
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

If I only return one of the columns it works perfectly, returning a array of results.

Comment: Look here https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-postgresql-jsonb-issue-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-1111/1224